# Algorithm to assign balls to baskets

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have a problem in mind and I am sure there is an efficient way to solve it without using brute force. Here is my problem:

I have X balls placed in a room and Y baskets also placed in the room. Each basket have room for an amount of balls in it, can differ from basket to basket. I want to find the combination that minimises the sum of the distances from each ball to its basket.

As an example:

3 Balls **(B1-B2-B3)**, 2 Baskets **(Bk1-Bk2)** and **Bk1** has 2 slots (room for 2 balls) and **Bk2** has 1 slot.
Combinations possible are: **(Bk1[B1-B2] Bk2[B3])** **(Bk1[B1-B3] Bk2[B2])** **(Bk1[B2-B3] Bk2[B1])**.
So we can compute the distances: **Bk1->B1**, **Bk1->B2**, **Bk1->B3**, **Bk2->B1**, **Bk2->B2**, **Bk2->B3**.
And for each combination we can compute the sum of distance and pick the smallest.

But is this problem a variant of a well known one? With a neat solution already existing? I hope so, and that someone could point me to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be solved using [min-cost-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) graph algorithm as well as using **linear programming**

Graph approach:

Make a fake source `S` and sink `T`

Connect `S` with balls using edges of zero cost and capacity 1

Connect baskets with `T` using edges of zero cost and capacity of corresponding basket

Connect balls with baskets using edges of capacity 1 and cost equal to corresponding distance

Find minimum-cost flow for **exact size**  `N_Balls`

**Edit:** `I missed Each basket have room for an amount of balls in it` , but it is enough to set basket-sink edge capacities into these values (old picture shows "large" capacity)

---

I modified wiki picture to provide exact flow value (`w(e)` is distance). Thick edges should have corresponding basket capacity.

[image]

[C++ implementation](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/min_cost_flow.html)

Perhaps you can find suitable algo in [Python networkx library](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/flow.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard problem but can be mapped as a variation to the *[assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#:%7E:text=The%20assignment%20problem%20consists%20of,it%20is%20called%20unbalanced%20assignment.)* which is a classic combinatorial optimization problem. Let me share my chronological thinking to approach this problem.

**The Assignment Problem:**

In this problem, there are several agents and several tasks, and each agent has a cost associated with performing each task. The goal is to assign agents to tasks in a way that minimizes the total cost, with each agent performing exactly one task and each task being assigned to exactly one agent.

**Mapping of our problem with it:**

In our case, the **balls can be considered as tasks, and the baskets as agents**. The cost of assigning a ball to a basket can be the distance between the ball and the basket. The problem can be solved efficiently using the *[Hungarian or Kuhn-Munkres algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)* or other similar algorithms.

**Why our problem cannot be considered a direct case for Assignment problem?**

The reason for this is that the ***baskets can have different capacities (i.e., they can take different numbers of balls)***. To handle this capacity constraint, you can modify the problem into a *[transportation problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transportation-problem-set-1-introduction/)*, where we can map the supply nodes as the balls, the demand nodes as the baskets, and the capacities of the baskets as the demand values.

The transportation problem can be solved using algorithms such as the *[transportation simplex method](https://www.ams.jhu.edu/%7Ecastello/625.414/Handouts/WV7.3.pdf)* or the *[minimum cost flow algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/min_cost_flow.html)*.

So in conclusion, your problem can be considered as a variant of the assignment problem with capacity constraints, and it can be solved efficiently using algorithms designed for the transportation problem.

---

#### References:

1. [The Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#:%7E:text=The%20assignment%20problem%20consists%20of,it%20is%20called%20unbalanced%20assignment.)
2. [Kuhn-Munkres algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)
3. [Transportation Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transportation-problem-set-1-introduction/)
4. [Trasportation Simplex handout](https://www.ams.jhu.edu/%7Ecastello/625.414/Handouts/WV7.3.pdf)
5. [Minimum cost flow algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/min_cost_flow.html)

Answer (score 1):

Let

- i index balls
- j index baskets
- c<sub>j</sub> be the capacity of basket j, a positive integer
- d<sub>ij</sub> be the distance from ball i to basket j
- x<sub>ij</sub> be a variable equal to the *fraction* of ball i to be assigned to basket j

We can formulate the problems as a *linear program* (where *optimal values* of the variables x<sub>ij</sub> are to be determined) :

min ∑<sub>ij</sub> d<sub>ij</sub>*x<sub>ij</sub>

subject to:

∑<sub>j</sub> x<sub>ij</sub> = 1 for each i

∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>ij</sub> <= c<sub>j</sub> for each j

0 <= x<sub>ij</sub> <= 1 for all i, j

A *feasible solution* is a set of values for the variables x<sub>ij</sub> that satisfies all the constraints above. An *optimal solution* is a feasible solution that minimizes the *objective function* given above. It turns out that if there exists a feasible solution there is an optimal solution that has the property that each x<sub>ij</sub> has an integer value, here that would be zero or one.

This linear program can be solved with the general-purpose *Simplex Algorithm* or with a specialized method used to solve *Transportation Problems*, the best known being the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://www.cs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/253/Syllabus/Transportation/algorithm.html).<sup>1</sup>

Let `B` be the number of balls and `C` be the combined capacity of the baskets. The Hungarian Method requires that `B = C`. If `C > B` we could deal with that by creating `C-B` more balls, each with a distance of zero to each basket. It would be more efficient, however, to create a single special ball `k` having the constraint

∑<sub>j</sub> x<sub>kj</sub> = C-B

with d<sub>kj</sub> = 0 for all baskets j

If the Simplex Method is to be used there are a number of public domain and proprietary LP packages that could be embedded in one's code.

<sup>1. Being a specialized method for solving transportation problems one might reasonably expect it to obtain optimal solutions more quickly than the general-purpose Simplex Method. In my experience, however, the opposite was often true for larger problems.</sup>